# TopologyKey in pod affinity

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

Where will this pod be positioned?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-anti-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx-anti-pod
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - nginx-pod
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/zone
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyISu.png)

this pod should be placed in the same zone of nginx-pod, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that zone label is typically used in cloud environment. You can check if your node has the necessary label first by `kubectl get node <node name> --show-labels`. If you are running in local mode, you can add label to your node by `kubectl label node <node name> topology.kubernetes.io/zone=<zone>`, then update your affinity spec to use `topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone`